# Having trouble referencing a Web Service from VS2012

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to put a reference to a web service into my VS2012 project.  The service is located on the company intranet, and when I access it directly in my browser I get the standard proxy display, and when I click on the Service Description it returns the WSDL.  So that seems nominal.

However, when I attempt to add the web reference I have a problem.  VS2012 defaults to locating a WCF service, but there's a way around it in the Add Service Reference wizard: click Advanced button; click Add Web Reference button; enter the Url to the service in the URL field.  The wizard finds the service with no problem, but when I click the Add Reference button it thinks for awhile and finally comes back with:

[image]

At this point it doesn't matter if I click Yes or No, the result is an unusable web service reference.

Is there something I need to do to get around this, either as part of the discovery process, or perhaps manually adding the WSDL?